# Why are the FAROS and the RIL contents removed from AIM?

Tags: runways, runway-incursion

I was studying runway status light and I found that FAROS (Final Approach Runway Occupancy Signal) and RIL (Runway Intersection Lights) are deleted when I read FAA AIM. It is deleted in the FAA AIM CHG 3(12/31/2020).

> 2−1−7. STAND−ALONE FINAL APPROACH RUNWAY OCCUPANCY SIGNAL
> This change deletes verbiage to Final Approach Runway Occupancy Signal (FAROS) and
> Runway Intersection Light (RIL) systems content, including revision of
> figures representing their removal.

Is there any reason for it? Does the FAA no longer use those systems?